# Haskell Perform Arithmetic Operations on Ints and Double

Tags: math, haskell

I've recently been writing an interpreter for a basic programming language and everything has gone ok. However can someone advise me on the best approach to add support for doubles. Currently only Ints are supported but I would like to add support for Doubles too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> type Env a = [[Var, a]]

This is a family of types. `Env Int` is an int environment, `Env Double` is a double environment, and so on. This is not a type that can hold both ints and doubles, which is probably what you need.

A type that can hold both integers and doubles may look like this:

```
data Val = IntNum Int | DoubleNum Double
```

and then you can have your environment as

```
type Env = [ (Var, Val) ]
```

(I don't know why you are using a list of lists here).

You need to define arithmetic operations separately for `IntNum` and `DoubleNum` cases (and perhaps for mixed operands too if your language supports that).

Adding booleans and lists is straightforward, just add another couple of cases to `Val`.

You will have to deal with type errors that will arise in your language as it begins to support more than one type. I don't think this simple design is well suited for a statically type-safe language. If you want that, the design has to be adapted significantly.

Comment: Thanks, the reason why I'm using a list of lists is to allow for local variables within while loops.
I think once I get the double and lists sorted I will leave it there and not bother about type checking.

Comment: Almost made the changes, however I get a compiler error in this function:

    `initialiseVars :: [Decl] -> [(Var, Val)] -> [(Var, Val)]
    initialiseVars (d:ds) list = initialiseVars ds ((d,0):list)
    initialiseVars [] list = list`

The error is "No instance for (Num Val) arising from the literal '0' , Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num Val)"comments may only be edited for 5 minutes(click on this box to dismiss)

Comment: Why are you trying to initialize your variables to 0? Is 0 somehow special? If you want to do it anyway, you need to choose which 0 you want, integer 0 or double 0. Consequently, use `IntNum 0` or `DoubleNum 0` instead of plain `0`. Better yet, add another case to `Val`, say `data Val = ... | UndefinedVal` and initialize to that, and report an error whenever `UndefinedVal` is used in an expression.

Comment: I just choose 0 as an arbitrary value. But yes using Undefined is a better solution and has fixed it Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer would be to define an variant type that can hold ether `Int`s or `Double`s, e.g.

```
data Value = Int Int
           | Double Double
```

and modify the definition of `Env` and other types correspondingly:

```
type Env = [[(Var, Value)]]

data ValExpr = IVar Var
             | IVal Value
             ...
```

But if you plan on adding more types, I would consider using [GADT](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GADT)s.

EDIT: typo